# Windows Batch File Multiple labels back to back

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In PHP or Javascript and other languages as well, there is the `switch, case` statement as a control flow tool.  One of the neat features of that is it allows for multiple `cases` to be pointed to a single command group.  For example:

```js
    switch(abc) {
      case a:
      case b:
      case false:
        console.log("hi")
        break;
      case c:
        console.log("see ya")
        break;
      etc...
    }
```

So that if `abc` is equal to `a` or `b` or is `false`, the *"Hi"* will be logged.  Depending on the code, it can be a lot cleaner than calling from an object or tons of `if else or if x || y || z` statements.
I have a windows batch file where I'm doing the following:

```vb
    GOTO %1
    ..... stuff
    .... more stuff
    REM =================LABELS BELOW==============
    :-h
    :--help
    :-?
    :--?
    type help.txt
    exit /b
```

It's more detailed than the above pseudocode, but that's the gist of it.  It allows for aliases for the same argument  And it works.  If I execute `mycmd -h` or `mycmd --help` etc., I help the help file text displayed on the screen.

However, on the last line of my output, I get the error, `THE SYSTEM CANNOT FIND THE BATCH LABEL SPECIFIED -`.

The error might be caused by something else.  I have some `CALL` commands and `GOTO :EOF` statements, so that certainly could be the source of the error.

But I've never seen the logic I applied above before used in a batch file, and I'm wondering if there are some other side effects that I might not be considering.  Is it possible that I will encounter unpredictable side effects down the road?  Is this bad practice for any reason?

**Update:**

I hadn't posted my code, because I think it's hard to read, and it's a work in progress.  Basically, what you're seeing here is argument parsing. I'm parsing the passed values in to categories - imagine this example: `node --file=d.js`.  I'm calling the `--file` the param, and the `d.js` the arg.  And much of the code below is creating an array of each.

```vb
    @echo off
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    @SET "T=%1"
    IF /i NOT DEFINED T (GOTO -h)

    SET /a counter=1
    SET /a argCount=0
    SET /a index=0

    for %%x in (%*) do set /A argCount+=1

    for /l %%x in (1,2,%argCount%) do (
        call SET param[!index!]=%%!counter!
        set /a counter+=2
        SET /a index+=1
    )

    SET /A paramCount=!index!

    SET /a counter=2
    SET /a index=0

    for /l %%x in (2,2,%argCount%) do (
        call SET arg[!index!]="%%!counter!"
        set /a counter+=2
        SET /a index+=1
    )

    for /l %%i in (0,1,!paramCount!) do (
        SET "arg=!ARG[%%i]!"
        SET "p=!param[%%i]!"
        CALL :!p! !arg!
    )
    GOTO END

    :-h
    :--help
    :--?
    :-?
    type %~dp0\lib\help.txt
    GOTO END

    :--unzip
    SET "a=%1"
    IF /i NOT DEFINED a (
        SET "MASK=\d+-[a-z]+.zip"
    ) ELSE if [%a%]==["all"] (
        SET "MASK=\d+-[a-z]+.zip"
    ) else (
        SET "MASK=!a!"
    )

    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /a /b %dls%^|grep -iE "!MASK!"`) do (
        @7z x %dls%\%%i -omypath\share\icons
    )
    GOTO :EOF

    :END
    @echo Done
    ENDLOCAL
```

**Update**:  I don't know if this will be helpful for anyone, but the problem was with `SET /A paramCount=!index!`.  That let to always looking for a parameter with an argument no matter what, so that if my second parameter didn't have an argument, or neither did, it was causing problems.  I 'solved' the problem by setting `paramCount` to `!index!-1`, but I think the upshot of this is that it's quite difficult to pass arbitrary, potentially optional, parameters to batch files, and probably should be parsed differently than I have done - or using a different coding language.  That said, it's working fine now for what I need.

Comment: Use that kind of code when I have to, or more commonly `goto target%%x` As for your specific problem - Obviously, since you've not shown us your actual code, we can't see the label `-`. I tried with labels `-` and `-?` and succeeded, so you'd really need to closely examine your code and make sure that the `goto` statement is operating against the expected string and obviously that the expected label exists. Why didn't you just try `:-<nl>echo got to label "-"` (where <nl> is a new line).

Comment: You may avoid the "label not found" error if you use a `call %1 2>nul` command instead `goto %1`; of course, you need to also modify the code accordingly. You may check if the label was not found via the %errorlevel% value after the `call`, that is set to 1 in such a case (but _not_ changed otherwise).